# Resize and export SVG to PDF using ImageMagick

Tags: image-processing, svg, imagemagick, fabricjs

I'd like to convert this **SVG to PDF** with the size scaled up to **x10** of it's current size without losing the quality of the picture. The PDF should also be in **300 PPI**. How can I achieve kind of output?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="248.1" height="350.7" viewBox="0 0 248.1 350.7" xml:space="preserve">
<desc>Created with Fabric.js 1.7.19</desc>
<defs>
</defs>
<g transform="translate(51.2 34.1) scale(0.1 0.1)">
<image xlink:href="./cat.jpg" x="-512" y="-341" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" width="1024" height="682" preserveAspectRatio="none"></image>
</g>
</svg>
```

[image]

This SVG came from fabricjs `toSVG()` code. I can resize it using fabricjs, but I'd like to know is it possible to do this and how using ImageMagick.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. The SVG is nothing but a wrapper around your cat.jpg. Why don't you convert that to pdf? (which amounts to wrapping  your image with a PDF.)

Comment: I'm just trying to learn new things. My main goal was trying to build an image editor where I can put a lot of photos in there so that I can print it out like a photo book (e.g: like mixbook.com)

Comment: So what is the role of the SVG? Layout tasks?

Comment: The SVG is an output from fabricjs, it can be much more complicated as in it'll have more shapes, text, clipping and others. I'm trying to keep it simple here with just one image.

Comment: For security, SVG's `image xlink:ref` will not render in imagemagick. If SVG is not needed, pass the raster directly to IM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ImageMagick is a programm suite aimed at raster images. What you have is a format that mixes vector and raster content both for input and output.

ImageMagick can handle that, but only through additional programs that need to be installed:

- import from SVG with Inkscape or librsvg
- export to PDF with ghostscript

You can cutout the middleman. Inkscape, while being mainly a SVG editor GUI, also has a commandline mode, for example for export tasks. You can scale the SVG by multiplying the `height` and `width` values on the root element with your scale - do not change the viewBox attribute:

```
<svg width="2481" height="3507" viewBox="0 0 248.1 350.7" ...>
```

Or, if you know the target size of the pages you want, you can set them. Even if aspect ratio does not fit, your content will sized-to-fit on the page. For example with a A4 page:

```
<svg width="210mm" height="297mm" viewBox="0 0 248.1 350.7" ...>
```

Then execute Inkscape:

```
inkscape --without-gui --export-pdf=out.pdf in.svg
```

Pictures are embeded as-is, so you do not loose resolution.

Comment: Tried your suggestion and it works. Thanks a lot. So basically I need to manually change the width and height of the svg, right? Is this a normal way to resize SVG?

Comment: For a standalone SVG file, there might often be an environment that can define sizes (like a html page embedding the svg as an image). Inkscape PDF export does not offer this ability (although it would not be that complicated), so it's more a substitute solution. Depending on your workflow, it could be a variant to treat the SVG with altered sizes as a temporary file.